# How to get column value from sql to label without code behind

Tags: asp.net

I am new to programming and please tell me how to get a column value retrieved from MS Sql database to a label. I hav got the data from sql as follows

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ShopsConnectionStringM"].ConnectionString);
 con.Open();
 sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select UserName,Email,ShopCountry,PIN,ShopName,ShopCity,ShopDistrict,ShopState, Location,ShopBoard from Shops_Table where UserName= '" + HiddenField1.Value + "'", con);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 sda.Fill(dt);
```

now i have an asp .net label

```
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

How do i get the value of column "Email" to Label5 ?

is it possible to do like this?

```
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Email")%>'></asp:Label>
```

I dont want to use code behind or c#.

Please help.

Comment: For your own safety use SQL parameters, don't concatenate strings

Comment: ok , can you give me a solution ?@kblok

Comment: *"I dont want to use code behind or c#."* - Then ASP.NET with C# probably wasn't the best choice of technologies.  Why exactly don't you want to simply set the value of the label in your code?  `Label5.Text = someValue;`  Or create a property in your page's class and bind the value to that?  Is the `Label` part of some larger data-bound control and you want to bind the `DataTable` to that control?

Comment: @Mansoor: More information about SQL parameters in ADO.NET code can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/328193

Comment: This is just for learning purpose

Comment: @Mansoor: Then that sounds like an *ideal* opportunity to, well, learn things.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement this. One could be using a FormView:

Markup

```
<asp:FormView ID="formView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span><%# Eval("Email") %></span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Code Beside

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ShopsConnectionStringM"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select UserName,Email,ShopCountry,PIN,ShopName,ShopCity,ShopDistrict,ShopState, Location,ShopBoard from Shops_Table where UserName= '" + HiddenField1.Value + "'", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
formView.DataSource = dt;
formView.DataBind();
```

Another way could be using the Page DataBind, e.g.:

Markup

```
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Email %>'></asp:Label>
```

Code Beside

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ShopsConnectionStringM"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select UserName,Email,ShopCountry,PIN,ShopName,ShopCity,ShopDistrict,ShopState, Location,ShopBoard from Shops_Table where UserName= '" + HiddenField1.Value + "'", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

Email = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("Email);
DataBind(); //This is the Page data bind
```

You will need to declare Email as a property.

```
protected string Email { get; set; }
```